# AWK dictionary not storing value between lines

Tags: awk

I'm trying to deduplicate the output of an awk script by storing each word seen as the key in a dictionary, with the number of times it's been seen as the value, and only printing the word if the dictionary was zero before the increment. E.g.:

```
match($0, /^(\w+)$/, a) { if (!$seen[a[1]]++) print a[1], "new word" }
```

however, this doesn't seem to work. The value of `$seen[a[1]]` is *always* zero, even if the output of the print statement shows the exact same word. I've been stuck on this for awhile now. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: `$seen[a[1]]` is referring to a column position, eg, if `seen[a[1]] == 0` then `$seen[a[1]] == $0`; if `seen[a[1]] == 3` then `$seen[a[1]] == $3`; so, remove the `$` and see if that does what you want?

Comment: Hell yeah! That's probably the issue!

Comment: In awk, `$` is a unary operator that coerces the following value into an integer (let's call it `n`) and then returns the textual value of the nth field of the current record (with n=0 meaning the entire record). Variables in awk, like C, are not accessed with a prefixed sigil.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @markp-fuso for providing the answer: unlike in Bash, in Awk, you can access a variable without a dollar sign in front of it, so `$seen[a[1]]` actually refers to the column corresponding to whatever the value of `seen[a[1]]` is (e.g. if `seen[a[1]] == 0`, then `$seen[a[1]] == $0` and so on), so I just needed to reference it without the dollar sign.